# Create CSS custom properties from SCSS variables

Tags: css, sass

I have an SCSS map of colour names and values.  I want to create CSS custom properties from them like so:

**SCSS**

```scss
$colours:(
  "gray-500":    #f7fafc,
  "red-500":     #f56565,
  "green-500":   #48bb78
);
```

**Desired resultant CSS**

```css
--gray-500:  #f7fafc;
--red-500:   #f56565;
--green-500: #48bb78;
```

I know how to loop through the map, but where I'm getting caught up is how to use the key as a custom property name, and how to prepend `--` to it.  All the examples I can find related to this topic involve manually typing out the custom property name - not gleaning it from the key of a map.

This is what I have so far:

```scss
@each $colour, $value in $colours {
    --#{$colour}:$value;
}
```

That generates an error: `expected "{"` with the caret pointing to the end of this line:

```scss
--#{$colour}:$value;
```

I'm using Dart Sass 1.23.7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On [SCSS to CSS](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css) you can use the following:

```
:root {
  $colours:(
    "gray-500": #f7fafc,
    "red-500": #f56565,
    "green-500": #48bb78
  );

  @each $key_name, $value in $colours {
    --#{$key_name}: #{$value};
  }
}
```

[**demo on jsfiddle.net**](https://jsfiddle.net/vgwm2k9s/)

On [SASS to CSS](https://www.sassmeister.com/) you have to use the `@each` inside a `:root` element (or defining an element inside):

```
$colours:(
  "gray-500": #f7fafc,
  "red-500": #f56565,
  "green-500": #48bb78
);

:root {
  @each $key, $value in $colours {
    --#{$key}: #{$value};
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought.  I'm getting an error saying `expected "{"` at the end of that line.  I'll update my question.

Comment: @Quasipickle because you need to place the variable inside an element: `:root {
@each $key_name, $value in $colours {
  --#{$key_name}: $value;
}
}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif Wrapping that loop inside `:root{ }` had no affect.

Comment: @Quasipickle it worked for me using this: https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: @TemaniAfif You're right.  I had duplicated the code inside `:root`, but hadn't removed it from my other loop - which was causing the problem.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch The `:root` declaration, and `#{$value}` was what I was missing.  It's working now - thanks.

Comment: It won't work for me. Can you please check [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4oq97m2/2/)

Comment: @AGoranov - fixed the SCSS code (value on @each): https://jsfiddle.net/vgwm2k9s/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create CSS custom properties from nested sass map, you can do the following:

```
    @use "sass:meta";
    // create mixin
    @mixin map-scss-vars-into-css-vars($map, $prefix, $key: "") {
        @each $name, $value in $map {

            // copy the map key
            $key-copy: $key;
            // create name for CSS custom property that contains:
            // current key + child key from nested map
            $key: #{$key}-#{$name};
    
            @if meta.type-of($value) == "map" {
                // if value is a map, invoke it once more
                @include map-scss-vars-into-css-vars($value, $prefix, $key);
            } @else {
                --#{$prefix}#{$key}: #{$value};
            }
            // next iteration of loop should go with unchanged key
            $key: $key-copy;
        }
    }
```

**How to use**

```
// define your nested map

$config: (
    button: (
        primary: (
            color: red,
            background: blue,
        ),
        secondary: (
            color: yellow,
            background: green,
        ),
        tertiary: (
            color: white,
            background: black,
        ),
    ),
    input: (
        primary: (
            width: 100px,
        ),
    ),
);

// include magical mixin

:root {
    @include map-scss-vars-into-css-vars($config, 'my-cool-app');
}

// the result is astonishing

--my-cool-app-button-primary-color: red;
--my-cool-app-button-primary-background: blue;
--my-cool-app-button-secondary-color: yellow;
--my-cool-app-button-secondary-background: green;
--my-cool-app-button-tertiary-color: white;
--my-cool-app-button-tertiary-background: black;
--my-cool-app-input-primary-width: 100px;
```